# How to check if Joomla path is routable

Tags: joomla-3.x, jroute, router

Is there any way to see if a path will route to a component preferably without dispatching it?  I can't use CURL or get_headers to see if the status is 200.  In other frameworks you can tap into the route definitions.  Is there something like that within Joomla? For example, inside a plugin/component/module if I want to check if '/some/url/here/' is a valid path.

```
$isPathRouteable = JSomeRouteClass::isPathRouteable('/some/path/here/');
```

or

```
$routeInfo = JSomeRouteClass::getPathInfo('/some/path/here/');
```

and have it return a boolean or route information.